Restricting the argument of a callback passed to another function
Consider the following TypeScript function:
function example<T>(
  ...[callback, batch]:
    | [callback: (param: T) => void, batch?: false]
    | [callback: (param: T[]) => void, batch: true]
) {
  if (batch) {
    callback([]);
  } else {
    callback({} as T);
  }
}

The callback type definition specifies its argument type, so one would expect the argument type to be inferred in the following calls:
example<string>((param) => {});        // Param should be inferred as string
example<string>((param) => {}, true);  // Param should be inferred as string[]

However TypeScript complains it cannot infer the type of param:
error TS7006: Parameter 'param' implicitly has an 'any' type.

example<string>((param) => {});
                 ~~~~~

error TS7006: Parameter 'param' implicitly has an 'any' type.

example<string>((param) => {}, true);
                 ~~~~~

Providing a explicit type does fix the problem but I believe TypeScript has enough information to infer it by itself. In fact, TypeScript does report incorrect typings when providing an invalid explicit type:
error TS2345: Argument of type '[(param: number) => void]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[callback: (c: string) => void, batch?: false | undefined] | [callback: (c: string[]) => void, batch: true]'.
  Type '[(param: number) => void]' is not assignable to type '[callback: (c: string) => void, batch?: false | undefined]'.
    Type at position 0 in source is not compatible with type at position 0 in target.
      Type '(param: number) => void' is not assignable to type '(c: string) => void'.
        Types of parameters 'param' and 'c' are incompatible.
          Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.

example<string>((param: number) => {});
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

error TS2345: Argument of type '[(param: number[]) => void, true]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[callback: (c: string) => void, batch?: false | undefined] | [callback: (c: string[]) => void, batch: true]'.
  Type '[(param: number[]) => void, true]' is not assignable to type '[callback: (c: string[]) => void, batch: true]'.
    Type at position 0 in source is not compatible with type at position 0 in target.
      Type '(param: number[]) => void' is not assignable to type '(c: string[]) => void'.
        Types of parameters 'param' and 'c' are incompatible.
          Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.
            Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.

example<string>((param: number[]) => {}, true);
                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Is there any way to get this to work without the explicit argument type?

You've hit ms/TS#42987; you want this to behave exactly like overloads from the caller's side. This playground link shows the overload version, which is probably what I'd suggest as a workaround for callers. Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz That's indeed the same problem! Thanks for taking the time to report it to the official TypeScript repository  Overloads will probably do the trick. Speaking of which, can you use them in a function member of an object?

I'll write an answer when I get a chance. I don't understand what "can you use overloads in a function member of an object?" means exactly. You can definitely define objects with overloaded method call signatures, but the implementation can be tricky (see ms/TS#47669)... this doesn't stop you from writing them, though. Seems like a followup question that's not really well-suited to a comments section of SO, though.

This is currently an unimplemented feature of TypeScript, described at microsoft/TypeScript#42987.  A function that accepts a rest parameter whose type is a union of tuple types behaves almost like an overloaded function with multiple call signatures. Indeed if you start to call this:
declare function example<T>(
    ...[callback, batch]:
        | [callback: (param: T) => void, batch?: false]
        | [callback: (param: T[]) => void, batch: true]
): void

IntelliSense-enabled IDEs will show you completion lists that look exactly like overloads:
example(⎀
//      ^ 1/2 example(callback: (param: unknown) => void, batch?: false | undefined): void
//      ^  2/2 example(callback: (param: unknown[]) => void, batch: true): void

Unfortunately as you've noticed they don't behave exactly like overloads:
example<string>((param) => { });   // err
//               ~~~~~ implicit any
example<string>((param) => { }, true);  // err
//               ~~~~~ implicit any

If you rewrite that function to be genuine overloads:
declare function example<T>(callback: (p: T) => void, batch?: false): void;
declare function example<T>(callback: (p: T[]) => void, batch: true): void;

Then you get the desired behavior:
example<string>((param) => { });  
//               ^? (parameter) param: string
example<string>((param) => { }, true);
//               ^? (parameter) param: string[]

It's unfortunate, because unions of tuple-typed rest parameters can be a lot more compact than overloads with multiple call signatures, and they are more amenable to being generated programmatically. But until and unless microsoft/TypeScript#42987 is implemented, I'd suggest writing overloads if you want this behavior for callers.
Playground link to code

You could go with function overloading
function example<T>(callback: (param: T) => void, batch?: false): Array<unknown>
function example<T>(callback: (param: T[]) => void, batch: true): {}
function example() {
  const [callback, batch] = arguments;
  if (batch) {
    callback([]);
  } else {
    callback({});
  }
}

This allows you to declare multiple discrete ways to use the function without inter-tangling their declaration.

Thanks for your contribution @ug_! The function still needs to declare the parameters, but overloading is indeed the solution I was looking for!
